# export more than 100,000 rows to csv in vaadin

Tags: csv, vaadin, export-to-csv

I try to export data from vaadin table with more than 100,000 records to a CSV 2007 file because it support more than 1 million rows.
i try this code:

```
CsvExport csvExport = new CsvExport(exporttable,exportedReportName,exportedReportName);
csvExport.excludeCollapsedColumns();
csvExport.setExportFileName(exportedReportName+".csv");
csvExport.setDisplayTotals(false);
csvExport.export();
```

using `tableexport-for-vaadin-1.5.1.5` and `poi-3.10-FINAL.jar`

and i got this exception;

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.setRowNum(HSSFRow.java:239)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.<init>(HSSFRow.java:87)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.<init>(HSSFRow.java:71)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.createRow(HSSFSheet.java:232)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.createRow(HSSFSheet.java:68)
at com.vaadin.addon.tableexport.ExcelExport.addDataRow(ExcelExport.java:518)
at com.vaadin.addon.tableexport.ExcelExport.addDataRows(ExcelExport.java:469)
at com.vaadin.addon.tableexport.ExcelExport.convertTable(ExcelExport.java:264)
at com.vaadin.addon.tableexport.TableExport.export(TableExport.java:80)
at com.mobinets.fm.gui.views.AlarmStatusView$4.buttonClick(AlarmStatusView.java:605)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor277.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
```

Comment: Why do you use the POI library for this? XLS files are restricted to 64k Rows, with XLSX files it should work

Comment: whatever your `CsvExport` there does, it ends up using HSSF (XLS) and this can not do more than 2**16 rows.

Comment: It would need to use the XSSF instead of HSSF

Comment: @geert3 how to can i change from HSSF to XSSF?

Comment: You would have to do it in the `com.vaadin.addon.tableexport.ExcelExport` source. May or may not be straightforward. Many of Poi's hssf classes have a one-to-one xssf counterpart.